# SQL Server : left join results in fewer rows than in left table

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I am using SQL Server (I believe it is 2005).

I have `TableA` that has 2 columns and 439 rows (each row is unique).

```
+----------+
|ID | Name |
+----------+
```

I have `TableB` that has 35 columns and many hundreds of thousand rows (each row is also unique).

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Date | ID | Name | Blah1 | Blah2 | ... | Hour1 | Hour2 | Hour3 | ... | Hour24 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Each row in `TableB` has hourly observations and some other house keeping information. Now for testing purposes I am only interested in today's date i.e 4/19/2013.

If I do:

```
Select count(*) 
from TableB 
where Date = '4/19/2013 12:00:00 AM'
```

I get 10526, which is correct as there are 10526 distinct locations for which there is hourly observation data each day.

I want to LEFT JOIN TableA and TableB `on a.id = b.id`, which SHOULD produce a result that has 439 rows.

Unfortunately, the result has 246 rows. How can this be? Isn't a `LEFT JOIN` suppose to return all rows in `TableA` regardless of whether there was a match in `TableB`?

****EDIT****

The complete query I used was:

```
select * 
from TableA as a
left join TableB as b on a.id = b.id 
where RealDate = '4/20/2013 12:00:00 AM'
```

Comment: can u show complete query you used

Comment: @PSR - I have edited my original post to include the original query used.

Comment: Re-phrasing @LoztInSpace valuable comment: Add constraints (using WHERE) to the selection tables before the JOIN. Otherwise, these constraints act on the resultant output of the joins (and can reduce the rows to even fewer than the original tables).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from TableA as a
left join (SELECT * from TableB where RealDate = '4/20/2013 12:00:00 AM') as b
on a.id = b.id
```

Or this:

```
select * from TableA as a
left join TableB as b on (a.id = b.id AND RealDate = '4/20/2013 12:00:00 AM')
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you. I'm a newbie to SQL so did not know that the placement of the where clause in this case would make such a big difference. I'm curious though what my original query was actually doing then. If it did not make sense what was the result of 246 rows all about?

Comment: so, your query first did the left join, then after that it filter out the result by the where clause. Hope it makes sense. If it does not I can elaborate more.

Comment: what happened was that my original query returned `ONLY` those rows where a.ID = b.ID, which didn't follow the philosophy of a `LEFT` join. That is rather strange. But I will accept it and move on as your solution is the correct one and solves my problem. Thank you. Appreciate it.

Comment: It's not strange - it's the way it works. With no match on B.ID it correctly introduces an all-NULL row for B. You then check that B.RealDate = '4/20/2013' which fails.

 select * from TableA as a left join TableB as b on (a.id = b.id **AND RealDate = '4/20/2013 12:00:00 AM'**)` is what you were after I suspect.

Comment: @LoztInSpace - ahhh yes you are absolutely correct. That makes sense to me now. Thank you. The query that faisal provided solved the problem which is what you were indicating as well. Thanks.

Comment: it should be noted that the second query is going to perform much faster than the first

Answer (score 0):

Saw other answer , my 2 cents (as per the use case in the question : we want to apply the ReadDateFilter and then join):

we should try to follow below (lets call it query-1):

`select * from TableA as a left join (SELECT * from TableB where RealDate = '4/20/2013 12:00:00 AM') as b on a.id = b.id`

if RealDate belongs to Table A :

`(select * from TableA where RealDate = '4/20/2013 12:00:00 AM') as a left join (SELECT * from TableB ) as b on a.id = b.id`

i.e. apply filter and then Join

**Not** below (query-2):

`select * from TableA as a left join TableB as b on (a.id = b.id AND RealDate = '4/20/2013 12:00:00 AM')`

Reason : if RealDate belongs to TableA query-2 would actually pick all rows from TableA which is wrong